# How do I get a bitmap from AsyncTask and set it to my image

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am trying to use an AsyncTask to convert an image URL to a bitmap in order to set it to an image. I don't understand how to get the bitmap out of the AsyncTask so that I can set it to my the images I am creating in a loop. I also have tried to set the bitmap to the image inside AsyncTask. My understanding is that everything must be done inside AsyncTask but I am unable to reference the images I want to set the value for.

I have researched the URL to bitmap conversion and the AsyncTask but I can't figure out how to combine them to get what I want. This has to be a fairly common task. Why is it so difficult?

How do I reference my images in AsyncTask?

Can I return my bitmap and then set it to the image outside of AsyncTask?

Is there an easier way to set a URL as an image source?

I have included what I have so far.

Thank you for your help and taking the time to read this.

```
class BitmapTaks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

public Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(urls[0]);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e("img", "Error getting bitmap", e);
       }
       return bm;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
   //do something after execute


}
}
```

Comment: You can return your bitmap from your async's doInBackground to onPostExecute like you seem to be doing. What is the issue?

Comment: use picasso, easy as pie. (also, you only lack the very last bit of code (setting the bitmap to the imageview) in your code, you were almost there.)

Comment: your on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has to be a fairly common task. Why is it so difficult?

I'd really recommend you take a look into the [Android Volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728). It's made to abstract away all this AsyncTask boilerplate code. Here's a very nice example of how to set an image bitmap

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 
// If you are using normal ImageView
imageLoader.get(Const.URL_IMAGE, new ImageListener() {
 
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
            // load image into imageview
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
        }
    }
});
```

You can read more from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: What is the AppController object? I can't find an import for it. Is it an instance of another object?

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped greatly.

Comment: @lock -- Even I want to know what is this AppController object? I am getting an error on that. How did you solve the issue? Would be great if you can let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Simply define final ImageView variable linked to the view you want to fill with the Bitmap:

```
     //inside some method e.g. onCreate()
     final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPrettyImage);

     new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            /* here's your code */
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }.execute(/*your params*/);
```

Or you can create ImageView field in your AsyncTask extended task:

```
private class ExtendedAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView[] views;

    public void ExtendedAsyncTask(ImageView[] views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        /* your code here */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        for (ImageView view: views) {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
ExtendedAsyncTask aTask = new ExtendedAsyncTask(new ImageView[]{myImageView1, myImageView2, myImageView3});
aTask.execute(/*some params*/);
```

Comment: I declared my image view as final but in the onPostExecute section of my AsyncTask I am getting a message saying that my view variable can not be resolved. Why can't I see my view when I have declared it as final?

Comment: can you debug through it and see if it's null? or is it a compile-time error?

Comment: It is a compile-time error. It doesn't know what I am trying to reference. It also doesn't know what findViewById is in AsyncTask.

Comment: view should be declared final in method of Activity/View scope. https://gist.github.com/togramago/ccfb1f6bd2dd9622a114

Comment: In the return you used R.drawable.adjust_background as a parameter. I am getting a message that it can not be resolved. Why is that parameter used? Why am I getting an error? Is this something that I need to create?

Comment: It is just a drawable resource - you can provide yours, just place a picture in drawable(-%dpi) folder. My picture is named adjust_background.png so I call it with R.drawable.adjust_background.

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped greatly.